# Lost data docker gitlab on local osx

Tags: macos, docker, gitlab

This is how I run GitLab with Docker:

**Step 1. Launch a postgresql container**

```
docker run --name gitlab-postgresql -d \
           --env 'DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production' \
           --env 'DB_USER=gitlab' --env 'DB_PASS=password' \
           --volume /srv/docker/gitlab/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql \
           sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-12
```

**Step 2. Launch a redis container**

```
docker run --name gitlab-redis -d \
           --volume /srv/docker/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis \
           sameersbn/redis:latest
```

**Step 3. Launch the gitlab container**

```
docker run --name gitlab -d \
           --link gitlab-postgresql:postgresql --link gitlab-redis:redisio \
           --publish 10022:22 --publish 10080:80 \
           --env 'GITLAB_PORT=10080' --env 'GITLAB_SSH_PORT=10022' \
           --env 'GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=long-and-random-alpha-numeric-string' \
           --volume /srv/docker/gitlab/gitlab:/home/git/data \
           sameersbn/gitlab:8.4.2
```

However, when I restart or shutdown the computer, all previous data is gone.

Please help me, I am new to Docker and GitLab in Docker.

Comment: Are you sure that there was data stored before restart of your machine?

Comment: By previous data you mean git repository content or database content?  How did you restart docker after reboot.  Did you assume docker containers will persist and continue to exist after the reboot or did you do some command you didn't show to start up after the reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems correct and I do not see why the volumes wouldn't persist your data. When you've restarted your computer, you can try to start the stopped containers using these commands:

```
docker start gitlab-postgresql
docker start gitlab-redis
docker start gitlab
```

By the way, I'd recommend using [this docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file to setup your gitlab environent. Just download the file and run `docker-compose up -d`.